# Mongoose populating new paths in database

Tags: mongoose

I have an existing Mongoose schema that I'd like to add some new paths too. When I've added these paths and output an example document Mongoose is displaying the defaults on the new paths - which is the correct behaviour.

However, this data isn't persisted in the database - and should I in the future which to export that data and move it elsewhere the new paths data will not exist.

Is it possible to easily iterate over my existing documents and populate their default values to the database?

I have been looking at Mongoose's `populate` method but I think I am misunderstanding how that is intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) all documents which do not have data for the paths that you are interested in with the default values by using the [exists condition](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exists) in your query. For example:

```
SomeModel.update({somePath: {$exists: false}}, {$set: {somePath: 'default value'}}, {multi: true}).exec()
```